# How to get x and y offset position of legendItemClick in highcharts react js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, react-highcharts

Exactly I want is when click on each single legend items it will show dropdown on with there position.

Comment: Please add more information here and post some codes to explain what the problem you met and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using react, why not just find the offset x and y from the onClick of anywhere within the desired component.
Your question is incomplete because there's no attached code but what you need is an event listener.

To get one to show you the x and y offset of any component you click on, do this;

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
```

Now, create a function called handleClick and pass in the event as an argument like:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
 console.log(e.offsetX,e.offsetY)
    }
  }
```

Finally, give the component an `onClick` attribute and pass in `this.handleClick` as the function to be run like:

```
<div className="charts" onClick={this.handleClick}>
</div>
```

N.B: You'd ideally do all of this within a stateful component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution where you can find the `chartX` and `chartY` coordinates of the clicked place.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-xb769

Is it enough solution for your requirements?